# how to curve a plan entity to match a sphere surface?

Tags: aframe, curve, spherical-coordinate

i'm kinda new to aframe
i have a question : with the aframe-position-spherical-component, i managed to position my element in 360deg
but how can i "curve" my element? (to match the sphering display) (btw my element are

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/lib/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-position-spherical-component/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-image src="/static/cat.jpeg" width="3" height="1.5" rotation="0 180 0" position-spherical="10 90 180"></a-image>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

## first attempt to solve this :

for now i managed to get something near what i want, but the value were found manually and aren't perfect

```html
<a-curvedimage src="/static/cat.jpeg" width="3" height="1.5" theta-length="64" radius="3" theta-start="-32" rotation="0 180 0" position-spherical="10 90 180"></a-curvedimage>
```

## second attempt (with the a-sphere solution) :

kinda work, but image are mirrored, and adding a click event like to show an image bigger is difficult to achieve

```html
<a-assets>
  <img id="cat" src="/static/cat.jpeg" />
</a-assets>
<a-box scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" color="red"></a-box>
<a-sphere radius="10" geometry="phiLength: 20; thetaLength: 14.12; thetaStart: 65" rotation="0 210 0" material="side: back; shader: flat; src: #cat"></a-sphere>
<a-sphere radius="10" geometry="phiLength: 20; thetaLength: 14.12; thetaStart: 65" rotation="0 240 0" material="side: back; shader: flat; src: #cat"></a-sphere>
<a-sphere radius="10" geometry="phiLength: 20; thetaLength: 14.12; thetaStart: 65" rotation="0 270 0" material="side: back; shader: flat; src: #cat"></a-sphere>
<a-sphere radius="10" geometry="phiLength: 20; thetaLength: 14.12; thetaStart: 65" rotation="0 300 0" material="side: back; shader: flat; src: #cat"></a-sphere>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a-curvedimage>` is based on a cylinder ([source](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v0.9.0/src/extras/primitives/primitives/a-curvedimage.js)) so it may not fit well. 
So how about actually using the sphere geometry ?
[tldr fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/e6chng8f/31/)

### Geometry

You could make it look like a `<a-curvedimage>` using theta and psi properties of a sphere:

```
<a-sphere geometry='thetaStart: 45; thetaLength: 45; psiLength: 45'></a-sphere>
```

This should result in a `<a-curvedimage>`ish plane, but also curved in the vertical axis. Play around with the psi and theta to see more triangle, or diamond shaped geometries.

### Fitting into a sphere

This seems like a job for a [custom component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#sidebar) ! If you didn't use them before, check out the link, otherwise the component below simply copies the sphere radius and position and uses their values for the image.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {        
  schema: {
     // we'll use it to provide the sphere
     target: {type: selector}            
  },
  init: function() {
     let sphere = this.data.target
     // make sure the sphere radius and transform is identical:
     this.el.setAttribute('radius', sphere.getAttribute('radius'))
     this.el.setAttribute('position', sphere.getAttribute('position'))
  }
})
```

And simply use it like this:

```
<!-- the background with some position and radius -->
<a-sphere id='background'></a-sphere>
<!-- the inner sphere  -->  
<a-sphere foo='target: #background'></a-sphere>
```

### Z-Fighting

You should notice that the image is not visible, or it's distorted. By now we have two spheres with identical size and transforms so the renderer won't know which one is in front of the another.

You could deal with this easily - by changing the radius for the inner sphere:

```
 this.el.setAttribute('radius', sphere.getAttribute('radius') * 0.95)
```

Or you could move the inner sphere a bit towards the center - like in the provided fiddle:

```
// grab the inner sphere's mesh
let mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh')
// we need an axis - I'd substract the mesh's center from the spheres center
let axis = sphere.getAttribute('position').clone()
axis.add(mesh.geometry.boundingSphere.center.clone().multiplyScalar(-1))
axis.normalize();
// move the inner sphere a bit along the axis
this.el.object3D.translateOnAxis(axis, 0.05)
```

### Enlarging the image on click

Usually we'd use the `scale` attribute, but here we can manipulate the `phi` and `theta` values to make the image bigger. Also you should bring the image to front when enlarged, to prevent z-fighting between images:

```
this.el.addEventListener('click', e => {
   this.clicked = !this.clicked
   // preset values depending if the image is clicked or not
   let thetaLength = this.clicked ? 65 : 45
   let thetaStart = this.clicked ? 35 : 45
   let psiLength = this.clicked ? 65 : 45
   let psiStart = this.clicked ? -10 : 0
   let scale = this.clicked ? 0.95 : 1
   // apply the new geometry 
   this.el.setAttribute('geometry', {
    'thetaLength': thetaLength,
    'thetaStart': thetaStart,
    'phiLength': psiLength,
    'phiStart' : psiStart
   })
   this.el.setAttribute('radius', sphere.getAttribute('radius') * scale)
})
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ma30gt85/1/). It would be better to keep these values in variables (base value, and a delta), but i hope this way it's easier to get the idea.

Comment: hello @PiotrAdamMilewski. your solution kinda work. I remove the sphere, as it's not part of my project (i want to display 10 images in 360deg). 
The problem, is, with your solution, click on an image to see it bigger is really difficult to achieve. 
Also, I see the image mirrored, is that normal ?

Comment: If you want to make it bigger 'onClick' then you can manipulate theta and phi like i did [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/e6chng8f/40/).
the image is mirrored probably because it's on the back side of the mesh. A neat trick is to set the `material.repeat = -1` like i did [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/e6chng8f/43/)

Comment: Great. last little problem, if I want the clicked image to before on other one, I just do like `this.el.setAttribute('radius', sphere.getAttribute('radius') * 0.95)` ?

Comment: @xDelph you could make it like this: a) firstclick - set radius *0.95 b) secondclick - setRadius * 1. Does it work for you ?

Comment: @xDelph i've added most of this to the anwser

Comment: will test this tonight, will get you alert if it's ok. again thanks for your help